# Accessing objects using RMI

Tags: java, refactoring, rmi

```
Class FoodItem{ 
 private String name; 
 private int numCalories; 

 public FoodItem(String s, int cals) 
 { 
 name = s; 
 numCalories = cals 
 } 
 public String getName() 
 { 
 return name; 
 } 
 public int getNumOfCalories() 
 { 
 return numCalories; 
 } 
}

public class FoodItemServer 
{ 
 public static void main(String [] args) 
 { 
 FoodItem f1 = new FoodItem("Wispa", 254); 
 FoodItem f2 = new FoodItem("Apple", 45); 
 System.out.println( "Food Name: " + f1.getName + “has “ +
 f1.getCalories +“calories”); 
 } 
}
```

We've recently started using RMI and i'm struggling to understand it.

In a previous example, (I'll put it below) we used a factory to store our objects and used `Naming.rebind()` in the server class on the instance we called from our factory.

In the example above, i only have the Implementation and server classes, a factory is not being used, how could i re-factor the code so that i could access the objects remotely, would i use the `Naming.rebind()` again or is there another implementation?

This is what i used before:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;

/*
 * Creates the server for using RMI
 */
public class PlayerServer 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          System.out.println("Player Server Starting");
            try{
                PlayerFactory aFactory = PlayerFactory.getInstance();
                Naming.rebind("factory", aFactory);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to use RMI you need an Interface which implement java.rmi.Remote interface 
and your FoodItemServer must extends from java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject and implement this interface.

Additionally you need to register this class at a RMIRegistry which
has to be started additionally. This is a special server which provides an JNDI 
Interface.

A client can than ask the RMIRegistry in order to receive an instance of the type of the RMI Remote Interface using the java.naming mechanism,

Comment: Ok, i understand what you're saying, its similar to what we did before so, ill mess around with it in eclipse now and i should be alright, thanks Christian, ill accept your answer as soon as i can

Comment: Take also a look for EJB Technology or use WebService (SOAP/Rest) if possible. RMI is still possible but in most cases it is better to use these more sophistaced technologies if possible.

Comment: The RMI registry provides an RMI interface. JNDI provides an RMI interface. The Registry does not provide a JNDI interface. It isn't essential to extend UnicastRemoteObject, or to bind the object into the registry: there are alternatives in each case.

Comment: @EJP D'ont understand your comment. I am d'accord with rmi does not provide JNDI interface because RMI has its own naming mechanism like JNDI but the invocation concept is the same, but the rest is confusing complete confusing to me. Pls tell me about the alternatives.

Comment: Instead of extending UnicastRemoteObject you can call UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(). Once you have one remote stub from the Registry you can acquire others as return values from RMI calls. You can imagine a whole tree of RMI objects rooted at the one that's in the Registry.

Comment: Hmm ok. Understand. Ok i have to say that i am not completely familiar with Java 7 RMI APi seems to be more sophisticated. My answer refered to the Java 5 mechanism which in my opinion is not wrong to answer the question. With JNDI and RMI i am completely conform with you. I thought the RMI registry just used the JNDI mechanism. But another question to you: Would you suggest to anybody to use RMI anymore. I pointed also in my answer to switch to more sophistiaced technologies i hope you agree with that oppinion.

Comment: @EJP Ok i have to say you are RMI expert and beyond. Just the mechanism you describe is avaible since Java  1.2. I really never saw this kind of declaration or invocation and this kind of invocation implies a lot of background knowledge about the whole mechanism.

Comment: Unless you were programming in Java before 1998, which somehow I doubt, your comment about Java 1.2 is pointless. 'This kind of invocation' doesn't 'imply' any 'background knowledge' that isn't right there to be read in the Javadoc, which is where I found it when I read it. In 1998. When you say something 'must' be done a certain way, you need to make sure the documentation agrees with you. The question isn't about whether or not RMI should be used any more, but I see no reason why not, if it fits the requirement best.